# No suitable constructor found for entity type 'CoordinateSystem'

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, geospatial, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to generate a migration file with a spatial column in it (Geometry)
and I'm getting this error

> No suitable constructor found for entity type 'CoordinateSystem'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'epsgId', 'topology' in 'CoordinateSystem(int epsgId, string name, Topology topology)'.

is it because spatial data aren't supported in SQL?

The model that I'm trying to add to database:

```
public class Polygon
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public int AreaId { set; get; }
    [ForeignKey("AreaId")]
    public virtual Area Area { get; set; }
    public Geometry Border { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(7)")]
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public DateTime SelectDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: *"is it because spatial data aren't supported in SQL ?"* SQL Server has supported Spatial Data since SQL Server 2008 (if I recall correctly).

Comment: Please, post a [mre]

Comment: It sounds like you don't have a `Geometry` column in you database, but you do have a `CoordinateSystem`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Polygon.cs file needs to be using
`Geometry` from `NetTopologySuite.Geometries`